# Rename table, create the same table -> ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create table again, so I did the following:

```
RENAME DOCUMENT TO DOCUMENT_TO_DROP;

ALTER INDEX DOCUMENT_I  RENAME TO DOCUMENT_I_XXX;
ALTER INDEX DOCUMENT_II RENAME TO DOCUMENT_II_XXX;
ALTER INDEX DOCUMENT_PK RENAME TO DOCUMENT_PK_XXX ;
```

Then:

```
  CREATE TABLE "A"."DOCUMENT" 
   (    "SID" NUMBER(15,0),  .....
```

However this end with error:

> ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object.

but

```
SELECT *
FROM dba_objects
WHERE object_name = upper('DOCUMENT');
```

-> no rows!

after this i go back to original state

```
RENAME DOCUMENT_TO_DROP TO DOCUMENT;
```

-> no error all good.

How is this possible ?

Comment: Maybe a COMMIT is needed?

Comment: DDL doesn't need explicit commit, @Joop. Oracle performs implicit commit before and after the DDL statement.

Comment: yes it is not needed.

Comment: @Littlefoot thanks, of course. Maybe constraints then. But I better keep my mouth.

Comment: If it were a constraint, @Joop, you'd get "ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint" :), not ORA-00955.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the full `create table` statement. Do you have a nested table, perhaps? That would cause this error, as the `stored as <name>` clause would be repeated with an existing name, which would be visible in `dba_nested_tables`. (As seen [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/b4Uh6IvY?hide=448), using an example table from the docs.)

Comment: stored as is the issue! thanks! It works!

Answer (score 1):

You will see this if your table definition includes a nested table. From comments it seems that it does (but showing the full `create` statement would still be helpful).

As a simple extension of what you have shown, if I define a table type and include that in the table definition:

```
create table document (
  sid number(15,0),
  nt_col nt_type
)
nested table nt_col store as nt_col_nested_tab;
```

then I get the same error you do:

```
rename document to document_to_drop;
```

```
create table document (
  sid number(15,0),
  nt_col nt_type
)
nested table nt_col store as nt_col_nested_tab;
```

```
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

Depending on how it was defined (when it's a table of objects or of a scalar data type), you might see the nested table name in `dba_tables`, but it might only appear in `dba_nested_tables`:

```
select table_name from user_tables
```

| TABLE_NAME |
| --- |
| DOCUMENT_TO_DROP |

```
select table_name from user_nested_tables
```

| TABLE_NAME |
| --- |
| NT_COL_NESTED_TAB |

So the problem is that you are trying to create a second nested table with the same name. You can rename that as well:

```
rename nt_col_nested_tab to nt_col_nested_tab_to_drop;
```

and then the recreation will work:

```
create table document (
  sid number(15,0),
  nt_col nt_type
)
nested table nt_col store as nt_col_nested_tab;
```

and you will see the old and new parent and nested tables in the data dictionary:

```
select table_name from user_tables
```

| TABLE_NAME |
| --- |
| DOCUMENT_TO_DROP |
| DOCUMENT |

```
select table_name from user_nested_tables
```

| TABLE_NAME |
| --- |
| NT_COL_NESTED_TAB_TO_DROP |
| NT_COL_NESTED_TAB |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9H6DDON3)

If you change your mind and want to revert the name of the original table you will also probably want to revert the name of the nested table as well.

---

You might also want to drop the table and use `flashback table ... to before drop` ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/FLASHBACK-TABLE.html#GUID-FA9AF2FD-2DAD-4387-9E62-14AFC26EA85C)) to recover it; but test that and make sure flashback is enabled and suitably configured before you do anything drastic...

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when I tried to move the table from schema A to schema B.
The sql in my case looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE A.TABLE_TO_MOVE_TEMP AS
SELECT * FROM B.TABLE_TO_MOVE WHERE 1<>1;
```

Then I tried to rename table from schema B and A

```
ALTER TABLE B.TABLE_TO_MOVE RENAME TO TABLE_TO_MOVE_TO_DROP;
ALTER TABLE A.TABLE_TO_MOVE_TEMP RENAME TO TABLE_TO_MOVE;
```

The second ALTER stmt returns: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object.
In my case, there was a SYNONYM with the same name as table TABLE_TO_MOVE in shema A. I dropped the SYNONYM after that I was able to run ALTER stmt without errors:

```
DROP SYNONYM TABLE_TO_MOVE;
```

Note: you can check SYNONYMs in DBA_OBJECTS table where OBJECT_TYPE = 'SYNONYM'

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell, it isn't obvious at first sight.

Though, I noticed that you're enclosing names into double quotes. My suggestion is NOT to do that.

This is pretty much useless:

```
SELECT *
FROM dba_objects
WHERE object_name = upper('DOCUMENT');  --> DOCUMENT already is in upper case
```

Should've been

```
where upper(object_name) = 'DOCUMENT'
```

What happens if you run such a query?

---

I tried to do the same, to see what causes the error:

```
SQL> create table document
  2    (id     number constraint pk_doc primary key,
  3     id_2   number
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> create index document_i on document(id_2);

Index created.

SQL> rename document to document_to_drop;

Table renamed.

SQL> alter index document_i rename to document_i_xxx;

Index altered.
```

At first I though it might be because of a constraint, but - nope, error code is different:

```
SQL> create table document
  2    (id     number constraint pk_doc primary key,
  3     id_2   number
  4    );
  (id     number constraint pk_doc primary key,
                            *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint
```

Is it a table? Seems so, it raises ORA-00955:

```
SQL> create table document_to_drop
  2    (id     number constraint pk_do2c primary key,
  3     id_2   number
  4    );
create table document_to_drop
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object


SQL>
```

Perhaps it is some kind of a bug in Oracle. Which version do you use?

Recently, I had 2 database links with exactly the same name; when I tried to drop any of them, I got "ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel" error. DBA bounced the database and it "solved" the problem. Can you do that? I'm not saying that it'll actually help (besides, your problem is different than mine) but - if nothing else helps, try it.

Comment: Thanks! same things (tables are upper case in my case). I also thought that the problems are synonyms that also exists in other schemas. i dropped these as well -> same thing

Comment: I added some more info; have a look, please.

Comment: I use 19.0.0.0.0. (Full Version is 19.16.0.0.0)